# Shared Global Variable Between IntentService and BroadcastReceiver on Android

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-intentservice

I'm sort of confused by this, but I know on Android you can cache files and what not, what I'm trying to do is there a way I can have a shared global variable that all my services can access? This way I wouldn't have to use a file for something that's going to be just one variable basically. Basically I'd want an `IntentService` to update this variable, and then be accessible to a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Hmm, going to take a look at `SharedPreferences` maybe that will work here, unless there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Static data members are intrinsically unreliable, as you do not control you process' lifetime. Your process may terminate in between the invocation of components. Only use static data members as a cache, with data that you can re-create or re-retrieve if needed.

Comment: Okay I'll look at Simone solution; part of the reason I want to do this is to use the `GooglePlayServicesAPI` for `ActivityRecognition` which may pause delivering updates after the device is `STILL` for a while, and I need someway to get the last known activity.

Comment: @eWizardII: Simone's answer doesn't address the issue raised by CommonsWare.

Comment: corsair992 you're right. It would be nice to know something more about what eWizardII is trying to achieve. Are they running in the same process? Can you lose the data that you're keeping in memory? Does it have to be persisted? I think that there is plenty of possible solution till when we know something more..

Comment: I only need to keep the data for a few seconds, because after that it is uploaded to a database, they're not the same process one is for Activity, the other is for Location. The goal being that once each has gotten their data an Alarm goes off to get that data and upload it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is more a Java a question that is then applied to the Android context. Apart from that, you can create a class that holds your variable(s) and reference it from outside.

Your problem now is to get the reference to that object and for that there are two ways:

- Add it to the [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object that you will have to implement and declare in your AndroidManifest.xml. You then have to expose the getter and use the application context to access the object.
- Provide a single instance of your object accessible by a static method that returns always the same instance (Singleton pattern).

Something like this for the second one:

```
public class Wrapper {

   private Object mVariable;

   private static sInstance;

   private Wrapper(){
   }

   public static Wrapper getInstance(){
      if(sInstance == null){
         sInstance = new Wrapper();
      }
      return sInstance;
   }

   // setters and getters for variables
}
```

Be aware that you have to consider another problem. What about concurrency?
If you use a background service probably you're performing some work in an another thread and you might want your variable to be volatile or to provide some synchronization to ensure that the element always gets updated. If you wrap the variable that you want to expose you can control the creation of the wrapper and the access to the variables.